# как отправить данные из textarea

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

сори за глупый вопрос. не могу понять, как считать текст из `textarea`. есть вот такой код:

```
function pressenter(evt){
    ev = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
    if (charCode == 13) {
        alert();
        // Do stuff here
    }
};

<textarea class="form-control social-comment-form" name="body" placeholder="Write comment..." onKeyUp="pressenter(event)"></textarea>
```

хочу, чтоб текст, который написан в `textarea`, выводился в `alert`.
Может, нужно изменить код и вызывать все через форму? если так, можете написать, как это реализовать через форму?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У тебя код на чистом js, поэтому и ответ на нем же, без jQuery

```
var text = document.querySelector('.social-comment-form').value
alert (text);
```

Comment: а неподскажите как очистить textarea после сохранения данных

Comment: document.querySelector('.social-comment-form').value = "";

Answer (score 3):

```js
function pressenter(evt){
    var charCode = (typeof evt.which == "undefined") ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
    if (charCode == 13){
      
      document.querySelector("#comments").innerHTML += "<p>Вы: "+evt.target.value+"</p>";
      evt.target.value = "";
    }
};
```

```html
<div id="comments">
</div>
<textarea class="form-control social-comment-form" name="body" placeholder="Write comment..." onkeyup="pressenter(event)"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = $('textarea[name="body"]').val();

alert(data);
```

Comment: alert Выводит undefined

Comment: `input` -> `textarea`

Comment: Точно спасибо)) поправил ответ